# Specify size and maxlength for Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I need to change the size of textbox :

```
 @Html.SimpleTextBoxFor(m => ((ModifiableProperty<string>)m).Value.TheCurrentValue, new { id = fieldId})
```

I tried this

```
@Html.SimpleTextBoxFor(m => ((ModifiableProperty<string>)m).Value.TheCurrentValue, new { id = fieldId, @maxlength = "100" })
```

but doesn't work.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can try this too :

```
@Html.SimpleTextBoxFor(m => ((ModifiableProperty<string>)m).Value.TheCurrentValue, new { id = fieldId, style ="width:200px"})
```

Just change the 200px value for the size you want.

For maxlength I use the same syntax as you and it is working for me.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EL_Taille_Initiale, new { style = "width:50px", @maxlength = "5" })
```

Comment: Thank yu it 's fine; i need to change it dynamicly : reduce and extend with the length of value in text ??

Answer (score 11):

Take out the `"@"` character for your `maxlength` attribute.  You only need that for reserved keywords (i.e. `class`).  Also, you don't need the quotes around the number for `maxlength`.

```
@Html.SimpleTextBoxFor(m => ((ModifiableProperty<string>)m).Value.TheCurrentValue, new { id = fieldId, maxlength = 100 })
```

If that doesn't solve the problem, then please post what the HTML markup is being generated on the response page.

Comment: It'doesn't work : <input id="_Activite_Value_TheCurrentValue" maxlength="500" name="Value.TheCurrentValue" type="text" value="Vente et achat des voitures Apliqué modif">

Comment: @A.adnane with a maxlength of 500 you won't have that text truncated.

Comment: <input id="_Activite_Value_TheCurrentValue" maxlength="5" name="Value.TheCurrentValue" type="text" value="Vente et achat des voitures Apliqué modif">

Comment: @A.adnane The problem you're having is because the textbox maxlength will only prevent user input from exceding that value.  But if you are setting the textbox to an initial value that constraint won't limit it.

Comment: What i need is this :    @Html.SimpleTextBoxFor(m => ((ModifiableProperty<string>)m).Value.TheCurrentValue, new { id = fieldId, style = "width:"+((ModifiableProperty<string>)Model).Value.TheCurrentValue.Length }) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I am using a constructor for my TextBox that does not allow passing HTML attributes, so I had to add this to my `$(document).ready` function: `$('#textBoxID').attr('maxlength', 30);`
Doesn't directly answer the OP question, but offers an alternate starting point.